# How to prevent parent expand by overflow hidden child text?

Tags: css, sass

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <span>
    <h3>123</h3>
    <h3>111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</h3>
  </span>
</nav>
```

SCSS:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  span {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;

    h3 {
      overflow: hidden;
      max-width: 30%;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      margin: 0 1em;
    }
  }
}
```

The code in here:
https://codepen.io/arkceajin/pen/bKNOwX

Could see an invisible area inside `<span>`, and it will expand if increase the text contents.

**Expected result**: make the `<span>` align centre in `<nav>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `span` is a flex-container - so it should have `justify-content: center` if you want to center it's children along main axis.

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
nav span {
  display: inline-flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  justify-content: center;
}
nav span h3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 30%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <span>
    <h3>123</h3>
    <h3>111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</h3>
  </span>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is possible make `<span>` width to not contain the invisible overflow part?